# Public IP not resolving

Tags: networking, ip, bridge, proxmox

I have a Debian/Proxmox sever running and trying to add a public IP which is not resolving and im trying to figure out if its a config issue or out IT network infrastructure (which we do not manage) causing the issue.

The server ip settings are

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eno4 inet manual
iface eno3 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
address 10.84.174.167
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.84.172.1
bridge_ports eno4
bridge_stp off
bridge_fd 0

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
address 84.417.178.198
netmask 255.255.255.224
gateway 84.417.178.193
bridge_ports eno3
bridge_stp off
bridge_fd 0
```

Our firewall VPN which has the public ip settings are as followed

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 84.417.178.198
netmask 255.255.255.224
gateway 84.417.178.193
```

The proxmox server provides QEMU virtualization and instructions to setup the networking have been followed, by creating a bridge from eno3 -> vmbr1
vmbr1 has then been attached to the firewall vm and the same ip settings added there.

Is there any reason why this should not be resolving my end?

Comment: Obviously the address 84.417.178.198 can't be right, hopefully you tried to obfuscate your addresses? Additionally, what exactly do you mean "does not resolve"? "Resolve" is usually used in conjunction with DNS.

Comment: yes the the ip is obscured and by resolve I guess I mean route to a machine